# Is there a better pattern instead of decorating a data class with DAO?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a POJO on my project that maps exactly to a Dynamodb object, so I decorated it with dynamodb annotations.
The problem I see is that this couples the data to this specific persistence. In practice I don't think this is a problem, but it is a smell IMO.
Is there some other recommended pattern for this use-case?

Comment: I think this is not a code-smell because you are using a decorator class. Your "original" class knows nothing about the persistence. Anyway, can you show your code for a better understanding?

Comment: @Héctor I don't think he's using a decorator class.

Comment: @MauricePerry Oh right, I misunderstood it. He means that he annotated the class, but not decorated.

Comment: @Héctor yes, I think that what's he meant

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the alternative to annotating a class in this manner is to specify the mapping in external configuration such as XML. However, that has other issues: it's typically more verbose, prone to typos, and requires you to look in more places, for example. You'll need to decide for yourself which trade-off you prefer.

Comment: Is there an alternative with Dynamodb?